# Install neupy with python3.8.3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neupy

I got the following error. How to install neupy with python3.8.3? Is it not available on python3.8.3? I have a version 2.2.0rc3 of tensorflow

```
pip install neupy
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<1.14.0,>=1.10.1 (from neupy) (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<1.14.0,>=1.10.1 (from neupy)
```

Comment: some point: you have to install python x64, TensorFlow does not work on 32b. Use python3. Try to upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`


And give a try with `pip3 install neupy`

Comment: Thank you, I installed it ! But when i import  it to the project , I got the error like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'neupy' ". Why could it be?

Comment: Check if the package is installed into your project's virtual environment. It may be the reason. And also check you are using python3 in your project, so is pip3.

Comment: I have 3.8.3 python version but using python not python3. How can I use python3 in my project?

Comment: As `python --version` returns 3.x, the version is okay, you are already using python3. Unless check if you have python3: `python3 --version`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hasan, problem is solved with your help.